# Starting Tomcat add-on XAMPP not working

Tags: xampp, tomcat7

I installed  XAMPP 1.7.7, including:

Apache 2.2.21
MySQL 5.5.16
PHP 5.3.8
phpMyAdmin 3.4.5
FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.39
Tomcat 7.0.21 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector).

My all other services work expect for Tomcat.

Things that I did right now, to fix this:
I realized that I did not had java on my computer, as on command prompt there was no path for java. So I installed JAVA 1.7.0 and also set the "Environment path".

But still its not getting started.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 10):

Assuming windows os,

Step 1. Create/edit an environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with path to jdk (**important:- not to `\bin` but just `c:\java\jdk_1_7_0` and dont put semicolon at the end**).

step 2. Create/edit an environment variable `JRE_HOME` with path to jre (**important:- again not to `\bin` but just the folder where `bin` is located and no semicolon in the end**).

step 3. Create/edit an environment variable `path` that should be added like this,
`< all the previous path stuff's >;%JAVA_HOME%/bin;.;`

The xampp tomcat looks for `%JAVA_HOME%` or `%JRE_HOME%` individually, so just setting the `path` and `classpath` variables, up to the `bin` folder, will not work here. It works for standard Apache tomcat only.

Also, the your version of xampp have disabled the users by default. Enable it by un-commenting the user part in the `x:\xampp\tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tried these steps, and it still says  the following, any tips? 
 

    [XAMPP]: Using JDK
    
    [XAMPP]: Seems fine!
    [XAMPP]: Set JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15
    [XAMPP]: Set CATALINA_HOME : c:\xampp\tmp\tomcat
    
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    done.
    Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Did you restart the command prompt?? Check if the path has been created or not. Save settings and then restart the system just to be sure.

Comment: Yes I have done all those steps a few times. I've tried with and without the /bin even though I know it shouldn't have it. I have it set up just as the answer suggests. I have UAC completely off (and did when I installed xampp). I've tried with JDK 7 and 6.

Comment: Are you creating System variables or user variables. Also know that variables are case sensitive, so capital case only. Do not add the \bin.

Comment: I am using System Vars and yes they are all capitalized. One thing I think may be a problem is that the CMD message says `Set CATALINA_HOME : c:\xampp\tmp\tomcat` but the tomcat file doesn't exist in xampp\tmp.  Could this be a problem? I've tried to create a folder, and a file named tomcat, but it didn't do anything. I've since deleted them.

Comment: tomcat is a folder not file. You need to set catalina_home to the tomcat folder within xampp folder. Where ever it is located. On my system, It is d:/xampp/tomcat. Also Make sure there is JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME Pointing to proper location.

Comment: Got it working. Just created a few user specific vars. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute manually following bat file
c:\xampp\catalina_start

or

put

catalina_start ,
catalina_stop

in XAMPP control panel start up

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and it was caused by running a 32 bits Tomcat on a 64 bits windows. (I was using XAMPP 1.8.3 in a Windows 8 64 bits.)

First:

- Make sure you have `JAVA_HOME` system variable pointing to your jdk folder (not the `\bin`);
- Make sure `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` is in your `%PATH%` system variable.

The solution:

- Uninstall the Tomcat7 service if you have installed it already;
- Download a **64 bit version** of Tomcat 7 for windows (check [this link to get the latest](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgihttp://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) - I used the [7.0.42](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-windows-x64.zip) version);
- **Replace** the **`tomcat7.exe`** and **`tomcat7w.exe`** files of the `C:\xampp\tomcat\bin` folder with those present in the recently downloaded zip file.

Now you can install the service as usual (through XAMPP control panel, if you use it) and it should start just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the catalina.bat under the directory of C:\xampp\tomcat>

C:\xampp\tomcat>catalina.bat

CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"

Since %cd% echo the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

In environment variable add all these variable then catalina_start.bat will work

Variable      Key

JAVA_HOME     your java-jdk address

JRE_HOME      your java-jre address

Path          your java-jdk address ; your java-jre file address ; your java-jre/bin address ;  our java-jdk/bin

It took me almost 5hours to find the method to let xampp-tomcat to start :'(