# Tomcat unable to install error: Service was not (uninstalled)

Tags: java, php, windows, tomcat, xampp

I installed Xampp on my windows, and tried to install Tomcat on Xampp, but I keep getting the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnTjy.png) on my Xampp control panel:

> Service was NOT (uninstalled)!

I found some similar posts - [Can't install Tomcat with xampp control panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802895/cant-install-tomcat-with-xampp-control-panel) and [Starting Tomcat add-on XAMPP not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762818/starting-tomcat-add-on-xampp-not-working), but tried all the available methods mentioned there:

- Create environment variable for JAVA_HOME & JRE_HOME
- Make sure %JAVA_HOME%\bin; is in my %PATH% system variable
- Download 64 bit version of tomcat to replace the 32 bit version in xampp
- Go to C:\xampp\tomcat, clicked the tomcat_service_uninstall.bat, then return to xampp control panel and tried to install it again.

But none of these methods worked and the red cross beside Tomcat (under module column) is still visible.

Comment: can you add more logs of installation?

Comment: Typically the "JDK" installs *both* the JDK and the JRE.  "Java Runtime Environment" is just that: the JRE *only*.  It sounds like you simply chose the wrong package (JRE-only) when you chose Java 10.

Comment: I downloaded both jdk and jre. Not sure why it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't post your answer inside the question; post it as an answer instead. Answering your own question is good, but not as part of the question.